# Jquery selector for href links

Tags: jquery

If I want to use this link http://localhost:8086/IAPApp/lead/index.html so how should I write the function in jquery so that all pages which starts with /lead will get displayed.That means for any link which contains /lead in URl that should be displayed.I have written the function as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="IAPApp/lead/"]')
});
```

```
<a href="data-index.html"  style="visibility: hidden"></a>
<a href="data-riskAssessment.html" style="visibility: hidden"></a>
```

Comment: Your HTML/JS sample above seems completely unrelated to the description of your issue. Either way, use the 'attribute contains' selector, not the 'attribute begins with selector' that you currently are, eg `$('a[href*="/lead"]');`

Comment: Whenever lead links are vissible then other two links which I have given must be hidden .That is why I have written visibility:hidden

Answer (score 1):

I would use the *contains* `[attribute*="value"]` selector. You can view all available selector **[here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://localhost:8086/IAPApp/notlead/index.html">hidden</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8086/IAPApp/lead/index.html">visible</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').hide(); // Hides all Anchors
    $('a[href*="/lead/"]').show(); // Display only this ones who contains the "/lead/"
});
```

**[JsFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jjn95zfb/1/)**

Comment: This will work with only lead pages but if I want to use it with other links then?I mean if i contain various links which will start with /abc/ likewise

Comment: I have to hide other links also.How it is possible?

Comment: Hiding other links you can view in the example. What do you mean with other links? Have you got some example links?

Comment: Actually I have lead and manager as a role.Lead which internally contains 4 tabs those should be visible whenever we write above code and manager contains 3 tabs which must be hidden whenever we are using lead pages

Comment: You can also use more of the url in the `value` part like `$('a[href*="http://www.google.de/lead/"]').show();`

Comment: I am new for the jquery .Please can you elaborate more?

Comment: Then I have to redirect you to https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/